# I have a primefaces calendar has event change listerner

Tags: jsf, primefaces

this is code iam writing

```
<p:calendar mindate="#{BackingBean.displayMinimumDate}" requiredMessage="This calendar field is required" value="#{BackingBean.displayCurrentDate}"  id="calendarRevoteId" disabled="#{BackingBean.showingRevoteCalendarField}" valueChangeListener="#{BackingBean.processValueChange}"></p:calendar>
```

and I have written radiobutton

```
 <h:form id="form">
   <p:selectOneRadio id="resultVotingAction" value="#{votingResult.stakeHolderVoteVO.votingResult}"
                     rendered="#{votingResult.renderVotingOption}" styleClass="votingRadioControl">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approve" itemValue="Approve" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reject" itemValue="Reject" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Request More Info" itemValue="Request More Info" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Revote" itemValue="Revote" />
     <p:ajax listener="#{BackingBean.renderingCalendar}"  update="form:calendarRevoteId"/>                         
   </p:selectOneRadio>
 </h:form>
```

the problem i getting is processValuechange method  is calling second click and everything working fine on first click its not working

Comment: Is the `<p:calendar`outside of the form that contains the `selectOneRadio`? I suspect there is some mistake in your `update=`.

Comment: no its inside the form robert

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `showOn="Button"`to your calendar. That is Primeface's "Client side event that displays the popup calendar".

```
            <p:calendar showOn="Button"
                        mindate="#{BackingBean.displayMinimumDate}"
                        requiredMessage="This calendar field is required"
                        value="#{BackingBean.displayCurrentDate}"
                        id="calendarRevoteId"
                        disabled="#{BackingBean.showingRevoteCalendarField}"
                        valueChangeListener="#{BackingBean.processValueChange}">
            </p:calendar>
```